# Дефисное написание сложных терминов

Tags: орфография

Как бы вы написали слово "газо-термо-механическое устройство"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При записи конструкций, имеющий общий конечный элемент, при отсутствии союза и корректно слитное написание.

Правильно:  газотермомеханическое устройство. Ср. автомотовелогонки, электросветоводолечебница.

Но: газо- и электросварка, газо- и термомеханическое устройство.

См.[Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/30.htm#%D0%B7_03)

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: "Газо-и" без пробела не комильфо как будто. "См.Розенталь" тоже.

Comment: Вот и мне кажется... Ведь у него там "газо-пылевая туманность". Что же делать? Может быть, так: газо-термомеханическое устройство?

Comment: Уважаемая Аленка! газо... как первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно. См. Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.

Comment: Газопылевая - пишется слитно. Кого вы имеете в виду, говоря ''у него"?

Comment: Розенталя. Если пройти по той ссылке, что вы дали, то там в параграфе 43, в разделе "дефисное написание сложных прилагательных терминологического характера" есть пример "газо-пылевая (туманность)".

Comment: Вы сами написали: прилагательные терминологического характера. Там не говорится, что первая часть слов с газо пишется через дефис. кстати, в том же орфографическом словаре Газопылевой пишется слитно.

Comment: Давайте вспомним правило написание сложных прилагательных. Пишутся слитно сложные прилагательные образованные из сочетаний слов, по своему значению подчиненных одно другому, например:железнодорожный (железная дорога). Газопылевой подчинятся этому правилу: Газопылевой (газовая пыль). К тому же у Розенталя почему-то отсутствует в правиле  "газо... как первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно". Ср. в словаре Ушакова: газобаллонный.